# Flask Python Firebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase.

```
storage = firebase.storage()
storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("cat.jpg")
```

I can't seem to allow user to browse an image file from their PC and upload it to Firebase.
How should I go about doing this? Please kindly guide me in the right direction ,thank you!

Comment: You wanted to handle the upload from Flask ? Or from the browser itself.

Comment: @RajaSimon Um, I'm sorry but I'm confused by the question. I want to be able to upload files from the webpage (made using Flask framework), and then I will push it to the Firebase storage. Right now I just want to be able to allow user to upload a file, and then I want to be able to make use of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="file"..` to trigger the select window and may be listen the `onChange="handleUpload()"` event to handle your firebase upload.

```
function handleUpload(event) {
    // Use this event to get the input element
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (!files.length) {
      return alert('Please choose a file to upload first.');
    }

    // Always multiple files get the first file if no `multiple` in input
    var file = files[0];
    var fileName = file.name;
}
```

Comment: So I manage to get the file so far :
file = request.files['inputFile']

However it seems like I can't upload the file directly, 
storage.child("images/examples.jpg").put(file)